# Microsoft Excel (Office 365) acting really weird

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, dropbox, office365

I'm running Office 365's version of Excel on my laptop and somehow it's not working really well at the moment:

- Really slow in responding to user input through mouse and keyboard.
- When resizing the min/max/close buttons just disappear from screen.

[image]
[image]

Things I've tried:

- 1080k resolution instead of 4k
- disabled anti-virus
- Full online repair of office 365
- Sign in/out

All to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be caused by the Dropbox add-in for excel. Disabling that returned Excel to it's former glory:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good to know. Nice work!